# laravel 9: live version not loading app.css and app.js and my custom styles.css

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have uploaded my Laravel 9 application on my hosting. The `app.css`, `app.js` and `style.css` files are not loading in the public folder.

These links are on my app.php file in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/scripts.js') }}" defer></script>
```

All these files are in the `APPNAME/public/*`, either in the `css` folder or `js` folder.

This is the error that I get on the live version in the console:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I tried to run `npm build` before uploading the project on GoDaddy, but the `css` and `js` are still not loading.

Comment: Which line, in particular, is throwing the error? Is it the inclusion of `app.js` or `scripts.js`? Comment out either line to find the culprit.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa i commented out both of them but i still get the error.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa i commented out both of them but i still get the error.

but my main problem is that non of my css and js files are loading. i've been doing a bit of research, and i think the cause could be that i uploaded the project in a subdomain, and the instead of fetching the resources from the subdomain it is fetching from the main domain. if this might be the problem. how can i solve it